# How to change app.config settings on a win form app once it's installed on a client

Tags: c#, winforms, oneclick

I create a quick little win form application that I want to deploy to a user.
In my application I created several user settings so that he can configure it on his end once it's installed.

In my app.config I have:

```
<userSettings>
    <MyApp.Properties.Settings>
      <setting name="Custom1" serializeAs="String">
        <value>This is my value 1</value>
      </setting>
      <setting name="Custom2" serializeAs="String">
        <value>This is my value 2</value>
      </setting>      
    </MyApp.Properties.Settings>
  </userSettings>
```

In my Application I reference them like:

```
lblOne.Text = MyApp.Properties.Settings.Default.JobLocation;
lblTwo.Text = MyApp.Properties.Settings.Default.UmiLocation;
```

I click install and I don't see the app.config file on deployment.  I just see the ClickOnce Application installed on a path on my c drive.

Comment: that's because when you deploy an application in .net, the app.config that you see when debugging vs compiled, becomes the exeName.config also look into deploying your application as `ClickOnce App`

Comment: I don't even see that config file either

Comment: you should read up on how to access .Config file in .net also go to the bin directory where you compiled the code, and look for the Executable name of the app + .Config extension for example if I wrote a program called `JDS` I would see `JDS.Exe.Config` another side not.. if you change the name of the .exe file you need to change / have a matching name.exe.config for that file as well..

Comment: Ah yes.  I am using One Click Deployment to have the client install the app.  From there I don't see where its finding the config file.

Comment: The actual config file (on my ClickOnce app, anyway) is called `user.config` and lives at `C:\Users\stuartd\AppData\Local\Company_Name\AppName.exe_StrongName_awasmzssygzhap4yetcetcetcixoef4\1.0.0.0`. and it contains the user settings.

Comment: Hmm I don't see that in my instance..  All I see is the exe C:\Users\me\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Company_Name

Comment: Have you searched AppData for Company_Name? Clickonce deployments are a big tradeoff about convenience vs "not being able to find anything" :)

Comment: You could use something like procmon to see what file gets changed when you change the settings.

Comment: do you have a network shared drive where you can deploy it. also how is anyone supposed to run the application if it resides on your local

Comment: Yes I palced the on click on a network folder